# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Update Select Minus

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following update scrpit..

```
UPDATE LIMRA_Retail_Current 
SET AnnualizedWOExcessPremium = (SELECT   
                        ISNULL(ul.AnnualizedWOExcessPremium, 0)- 
                        isnull((select iul.AnnualizedWOExcessPremium   
                        from dbo.LIMRA_Retail_Current  iul
                        where ul.Distribution = iul.distribution
                        and   ul.company    = iul.company
                        and   ul.Year       = iul.year
                        and   ul.Quarter    = iul.quarter
                        and   iul.Market = 'Retail'
                        and   replace(ul.Product, 'Universal Life', 'Index Universal Life') = iul.product
            ),0) UL_MINUS_IUL
FROM  dbo.LIMRA_Retail_Current  UL
WHERE ul.Product    like 'Universal Life%'
AND   ul.Market = 'Retail')
```

How can I update the column AnnualizedWOExcessPremium using ALL the values of UL_MINUS_IUL. I want to use ALL the values in my update.

Comment: Well, the error is telling you that there is more than one row being returned from the subselect, so you have to decide - should the subselect only return one matching row, or should you be trying to use all of the returned values in your update.

Comment: I think you have logic issue in your query. You are about to UPDATE ALL rows on column AnnualizedWOExcessPremium in table LIMRA_Retail_Current without WHERE clause. Or.., if you are indeed going to do this, you then have design issue.

Comment: If you can clarify what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you. From what I can tell,the error is occuring because you are subtracting from a subquery that returns multiple values as it should. This query can definitely be optimized, but the logic doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your sub select just needs a SUM:

```
(SELECT   
    SUM(ISNULL(ul.AnnualizedWOExcessPremium, 0)-  isnull((select iul.AnnualizedWOExcessPremium   )
    from dbo.LIMRA_Retail_Current  iul
    where ul.Distribution = iul.distribution
    and   ul.company    = iul.company
    and   ul.Year       = iul.year
    and   ul.Quarter    = iul.quarter
    and   iul.Market = 'Retail'
    and   replace(ul.Product, 'Universal Life', 'Index Universal Life') = iul.product
),0) UL_MINUS_IUL
```